# 'Has + V3' and 'Is + V3' are these active or passive voice?

Tags: passive-voice

1)The show has started.
2)The show is started.

Are these active or passive voives?

Please give reason alse.

Note: V means verb form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I am guessing by context that "V3" must be the name your grammar book or teacher uses for the past participle. I have never met this abbreviation before, and I would advise you not to use it.

"The show has started" is present perfect. Traditionally it would be called active (but to my mind that is better restricted to uses like "He has started it". I would call it a *middle*, though that term is not customary in English grammar.)

"The show is started" is passive, and furthermore it is (simple) present passive. As generally in English, the simple present is not normally used for present events, but only for timeless or habitual ones. So we would only say this in a context like: "On Mayday we always have a procession through our town. The show is started by the Mayor exactly at noon."

**Edit**: the closest to 2. that is likely to be used is "The show has been started". This is passive, and is present perfect, since the starting has present relevance (the show is still running). By using the passive, you are putting the focus on whatever or whoever started it: it invites the question "Who or what started it?"

Comment: Some older grammar books refer to the "principal parts" of the verb.  In English a verb is traditionally said to have three principal parts, the infinitive, the preterite or simple past, and the past participle, in that order.  Apparently in Nepal (and possibly some other countries) it is common for these to be referred to as V1, 2, 3.  (I agree that elsewhere this terminology won't be widely understood!).